# Как написать InputIterator?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Есть некоторый генератор, который выдает значения.
Его интерфейс описывается тремя функциями:

```
void Next();        // Сгенерировать значение
bool Done() const;  // Значения закончились
T& Value();         // Текущее значение, movable
```

Получение значений в цикле выглядит так:

```
Generator<T> gen = ...;
gen.Next();
while (!gen.Done()) {
  std::cout << gen.Value() << '\n';
  gen.Next();
}
```

Как сделать итератор, чтобы можно было писать

```
for (T& x : gen) std::cout << x << '\n';
```

итератор должен поддержисать интерфейс [InputIterator](http://eel.is/c++draft/input.iterators).

Comment: Может быть, текущее значение должно быть все-таки неизменяемой ссылкой? А то странный какой-то генератор получился...

Comment: А если оно возвращается с упором на временность - то может, надо сразу T&& возвращать?

Comment: Хотите сказать, что T&& нельзя копировать? Не верю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итератор можно добавить через пару свободных функций begin и end.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct GeneratorIterator {
  // Поддержка std::iterator_­traits:
  using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
  using value_type = T;
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using pointer = value_type*;
  using reference = value_type&;

  using iterator = GeneratorIterator<T>;         // Более короткое имя, для удобства
  Generator<T>* g_;                              // Ссылка на генератор, он должен жить дольше итератора
  GeneratorIterator(Generator<T>* g) : g_(g) {}  // Конструктор

  // Требования Iterator:

  GeneratorIterator(const iterator&) = default;    // CopyConstructible
  iterator& operator=(const iterator&) = default;  // CopyAssignable
  ~GeneratorIterator() = default;                  // Destructible 
  friend void swap(iterator& a, iterator& b) { std::swap(a.g_, b.g_); }  // swappable

  // Требования InputIterator:

  friend bool operator==(const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs) { return lhs.g_ == rhs.g_; }  // EqualityComparable
  friend bool operator!=(const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }     // a != b

  reference operator*() const {  // *a
    return g_->Value();
  }

  pointer operator->() const { return std::addressof(**this); }  // a->m

  iterator& operator++() {  // ++r
    g_->Next();
    if (g_->Done()) g_ = nullptr;
    return *this;
  }

  struct proxy {
    T value_;
    proxy(T& value) : value_(std::move(value)) {}
    reference operator*() { return value_; }
  };
  proxy operator++(int) {  // (void)r++ , *r++
    proxy old{**this};
    ++*this;
    return old;
  }
};

template<typename T>
GeneratorIterator<T> begin(Generator<T>& gen) {
  GeneratorIterator<T> it{&gen};
  return ++it;
}

template<typename T>
GeneratorIterator<T> end(Generator<T>&) {
  return {nullptr};
}
```

Поддержка `std::iterator_­traits` обязательна для всех итераторов. Т.к. вспомогательный класс `std::iterator` объявлен устаревшим в С++17, то мы не будем его использовать и напишем все 5 типов сами.

Требования Iterator это CopyConstructible, CopyAssignable, Destructible, swappable, а также `*r` и `++r` которые перекрываются InputIterator.

Требования InputIterator это Iterator, EqualityComparable с дополнительным `a != b`, также `*a`, `a->m`, `++r`, `(void)r++` и `*r++`.

Требование `*r++` самое сложное, т.к. требует вспомогательного класса куда надо переместить значение. Если значение некопируемое, то от этого надо отказаться и оставить только поддержку `(void)r++`.

`InputIterator` не гарантирует что если `a == b`, то `++a == ++b`.
Поэтому в данной реализации также не гарантируется что если `a == b`, то `++a == b`,
т.е. инкремент итератора инвалидирует его копии.
Это позволяет не писать `(lhs.g_ && lhs.g_->Done()) == (rhs.g_ && rhs.g_->Done())` в операторе сравнения.

Comment: Столько слов, а главный секрет реализации не раскрыт... Оператор сравнения можно писать через сравнение указателей на генератор благодаря тому что мы обнуляем этот указатель после окончания последовательности.